# Плавное появление вложенных элементов

Tags: jquery

Как при помощи jquery можно реализовать следующую логику?

1. Пользователь скролит до #wrapper.
2. Когда wrapper находится в зоне видимости, то по очереди проявляются .element.

http://jsfiddle.net/L5omxoeq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так http://jsfiddle.net/L5omxoeq/1/
для 2-х блоков http://jsfiddle.net/L5omxoeq/10/

Comment: огромное спасибо. то что нужно.

Comment: пытался для 2го блока схожий эффект приделать, но не получилось. подскажите пожалуйста где ошибся.

Comment: Дайте ссылочку, поглядим, но, скорее всего, метод unbind - снимает обработчик скролла.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L5omxoeq/1/ все там же)

Comment: Нажмите Update - и ссылка перегенирируется

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L5omxoeq/9/

Comment: обновил ответ